# Delete rows from SQL Server with WHERE statement from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to delete some rows from a table, based on a mixed where statement from two tables.

I tried this:

```
delete from tblI t1, tblS t2 
where t2.rcode = 'ALA' and t1.sid > 5
```

but I get a syntax error. Please help me figure this out

Changed it to JOINS:

```
delete from tblI
inner join tblS
on tblI.sourceid = tblS.sourceid
where tblS.rcode = 'ALA' and tblI.sourceid > 5
```

but something is still wrong, please help.

Comment: First stop using implied syntax that is a very poor programming technique! In fact you havea cross join as it stands, so likely the query would have been bad even if it worked.

Comment: What is implied syntax? Just so I can avoid this myself!

Comment: how are tblI and tblS related?

Comment: by "implied syntax" I believe he means the implicit join syntax, i.e. comma-separated list of tables instead of `JOIN ... ON` or `JOIN ... USING`.

Comment: @HLGEM - with a name that is an acronym, an avatar of swirly colors, and no info in  your profile we have no way of knowing if you are a lady

Comment: @JNK and what about you, JNK ?? :-)

Comment: @marc - Good point.  I'm a dude, I'll update my profile.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to tell it which table to delete from.

```
delete t1
from tblI t1 
join tblS t2  on t1.sid = t2.sid
where t2.rcode = 'ALA' 
and  t1.sid > 5
```